# NserviceBus - NHibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: -1; expected: 1

Tags: nservicebus

I am using below versions

NServiceBus : 5.2.14

NServiceBus.Host : 6.0.0

NServiceBus.NHibernate : 6.2.7

I am using NSB5 with Nibernate persistence and sql server transport. My service used to work fine before I move the queues to different the database, I created all queues in another database. Audit and Error queue remains on same database (Other NSB hosts are using same queues). I deleted all the old subscriptions entries from other endpoints, restarted services and check but subscription entries are not coming in new tables and give below error logs. What can be solution?

```
 018-10-16 07:11:03.2878 Info NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver Failed to process message
    NHibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: -1; expected: 1
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.Expectations.VerifyOutcomeBatched(Int32 expectedRowCount, Int32 rowCount)
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientBatchingBatcher.DoExecuteBatch(IDbCommand ps)
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteBatchWithTiming(IDbCommand ps)
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteBatch()
       at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
       at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
       at NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.NHibernate.SubscriptionPersister.Subscribe(Address address, IEnumerable`1 messageTypes) in C:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\Subscriptions\SubscriptionPersister.cs:line 41
       at NServiceBus.SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Subscriptions\MessageDrivenSubscriptions\SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.cs:line 76
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
       at NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line 42
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
       at NServiceBus.Persistence.NHibernate.OpenSqlConnectionBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\SharedSession\OpenSqlConnectionBehavior.cs:line 43
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
       at NServiceBus.ChildContainerBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ChildContainerBehavior.cs:line 17
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
       at NServiceBus.ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Monitoring\ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.cs:line 23
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<InvokeNext>b__0() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 95
       at NServiceBus.AuditBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Audit\AuditBehavior.cs:line 20
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
       at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 52
       at NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.Execute[T](BehaviorChain`1 pipelineAction, T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line 129
       at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 413
       at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 344
       at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.TryProcess(TransportMessage message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line 230
       at NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer.AmbientTransactionReceiveStrategy.TryReceiveFrom(TableBasedQueue queue) in C:\BuildAgent\work\888dd942b44bad5a\src\NServiceBus.SqlServer\AmbientTransactionReceiveStrategy.cs:line 57
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Answer from NserviceBus discussion below
https://discuss.particular.net/t/nhibernate-stalestateexception-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-from-update-actual-row-count-1-expected-1/817

Code

```
public class CustomDriverConnectionProvider : 
NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
{
public override System.Data.IDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    var conn = base.GetConnection();
    DisableNoCount(conn);
    return conn;
}

private void DisableNoCount(System.Data.IDbConnection connection)
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SET NOCOUNT OFF";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
}

public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
    {
  //Setup NHibernate
        var hibernateConfig = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
        hibernateConfig.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
        {
            x.ConnectionString = GetPersistenceConnectionString();
            x.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
            x.ConnectionProvider<CustomDriverConnectionProvider>();
        });
        hibernateConfig.SetProperty("default_schema", GetPersistenceSchema());

        //Wire NHibernate
        configuration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence>()
            .RegisterManagedSessionInTheContainer()
            .DisableSchemaUpdate()
   }
```